# Should I download stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z to be able to use the StackedOff app?

Tags: support, data-dump, archive, community-data

I'm currently trying to use that app.

[StackedOff - an offline StackExchange indexer and search engine](https://stackapps.com/questions/8369/stackedoff-an-offline-stackexchange-indexer-and-search-engine)

During an internet GB restriction on my side, the stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z **file is 30 GB**; is that file important to be downloaded to run the StackedOff app above?

I would also like to know what GUI tool you can use in the desktop app to view Stack Overflow dump files.

I find that in the StackedOff app, I can't search with specific tags like we can do in the real Stack Overflow.

Are there any better/more features than the StackedOff app available in this community but with a GUI/Localhost local version?

Comment: *"If downloading stackoverflow.com, ensure you download the Posts, Users, and Comments files."* - There are instructions on the linked github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @NickstandswithUkraine mentions in the comments, the tool's [GitHub page](https://github.com/tools4j/stacked-off) says:

> Most of the sites are in individual 7z files. Except for stackoverflow.com which is broken up into a few seperate archives. If downloading stackoverflow.com, ensure you download the Posts, Users, and Comments files.

PostHistory is a different database table and a different file, so you don't need to download it. That makes sense, since the search engine only looks at *current* versions of posts, which are in the Posts table/file.

*(In general, if you have a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question about an app listed on Stack Apps, it's fine to post it as an answer there. The author of the app automatically gets an inbox notification; sometimes, they're the only one able to answer a question and they'll likely miss a Meta Stack Exchange question. I'm a moderator both here and on Stack Apps but I can't migrate this question to an answer on the Stack Apps post.)*